# Show that $\mathrm{PSL}_2(C)$ is complex algebraic

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\DeclareMathOperator\PSL{PSL}\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\M{M}\DeclareMathOperator\im{im}$I meet this problem when reading Artin's book Algebra. Following his way in exercise, one defines a map $\varphi: \SL_2(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow \GL_4(\mathbb{C})$ by considering the conjugation action of $A=\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ on $\M_2(\mathbb{C}),$ taking $(e_{11},e_{12},e_{21},e_{22})$ as a basis of $\M_2(\mathbb{C})$, computation shows that $\varphi(A)=\begin{pmatrix}ad&-ac&bd&-bc\\-ab&a^2&-b^2&ab\\cd&-c^2&d^2&-cd\\-bc&ac&-bd&ad\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a&0&b&0\\0&a&0&b\\c&0&d&0\\0&c&0&d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}(A^{-1})^t&0\\0&(A^{-1})^t\end{pmatrix},$ $\varphi$ is a group homomorphism with kernel $\{\pm I\},$ thus $\im(\varphi)$ is isomorphic to $\PSL_2(\mathbb{C}).$
My question is how to write equations on elements of $Y=(y_{ij})\in \GL_4(\mathbb{C})$ to show that $\PSL_2(\mathbb{C})$ is a complex algebraic group?

Thanks for your help and explanation!

Comment: There are classical results ensuring that the image is Zariski-closed, without writing equations. So, you should clarify whether you want to prove that it's complex algebraic, or if you want to provide explicit equations for the image.

Comment: Yeah, I want to write the explicit equations here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Nullstellensatz says that, if we have something that we know is a variety, then it is defined by all the equations that it satisfies—so let's just try to write down lots of obvious equations, and hope that they work.

By inspection, every matrix $X = \begin{pmatrix} a & b & c & d \\ e & f & g & h \\ i & j & k & m \\ n & r & s & t \end{pmatrix}$ in $\varphi(\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb C))$ satisfies $a = t$, $b = -r$, $c = -s$, $d = n$, $e = -h$, $i = -m$, $f g = -e^2$, $f j = -b^2$, $f k = a^2$, $g j = -d^2$, $g k = -c^2$, $j k = -i^2$,
$a b = -f i$, $a e = -c f$, $b e = -d f$,
$c d = g i$, $c e = a g$, $d e = b g$,
$b d = e j$, $b i = a j$, $d i = c j$,
$a c = -e k$, $a i = -b k$, $c i = -d k$, and
$a d = b c$, and
$a + d = 1$.
(Almost certainly there are redundancies here, but that's OK.)
Suppose conversely that these equations are satisfied.

One of $f$, $g$, $j$, or $k$ is non-$0$ (or else our equations would force the matrix to have determinant $0$, whereas actually it has determinant $(a + d)^4 = 1$).  Suppose that $f$ is non-$0$.
Put $\alpha = \sqrt f$, $\beta = \sqrt{-g}$, $\gamma = \sqrt{-j}$, and $\delta = \sqrt k$, with the square roots chosen so that the equalities $\alpha\beta = -e$, $\alpha\gamma = -b$, and $\alpha\delta = a$ hold.  Since $\alpha^2\beta\gamma$ equals both $b e = -d f$ and $f\beta\gamma$, we have that $\beta\gamma$ equals $-d$.  Similarly, $\beta\delta$ equals $c$ and $\gamma\delta$ equals $i$, so $X$ equals $\begin{pmatrix} \alpha\delta & -\alpha\gamma & \beta\delta & -\beta\gamma \\ -\alpha\beta & \alpha^2 & -\beta^2 & \alpha\beta \\ \gamma\delta & -\gamma^2 & \delta^2 & -\gamma\delta \\ -\beta\gamma & \alpha\gamma & -\beta\delta & \alpha\delta \end{pmatrix}$.  In particular, $\alpha\delta - \beta\gamma$ equals $a + d = 1$, so $\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ \gamma & \delta \end{pmatrix}$ belongs to $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb C)$, and $X$ equals $\varphi\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ \gamma & \delta \end{pmatrix}$.

We assumed that $f$ was non-$0$, but similar reasoning works when $g$ is non-$0$, when $j$ is non-$0$, and when $k$ is non-$0$.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!